# 1D Poisson equation and quadratic basis functions assembly

Tags: finite-element, python, poisson, elliptic-pde

I'm solving the simple Poisson problem $$-u''(x)=1$$ in the interval $[0,1]$ with $u(0)=u(1)=0$.

I discretised my domain as done [here](http://hplgit.github.io/INF5620/doc/pub/sphinx-fem/._main_fem003.html#example-on-piecewise-quadratic-finite-element-functions), i.e. with

`nodes = [0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1.0]`
and
`elements = [[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8]]`

I'm trying to assemble the matrix and the r.h.s by looping over the elements, and I found the same results of [here](https://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/%7Ekuzmin/cfdintro/lecture7.pdf) (see pag. 22 for the matrix and load vector)

$$A_K=\frac{1}{3h}
\begin{bmatrix}
7 & -8 & 1 \\
-8 & 16 & -8 \\
1 & -8 & 7
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and $$F_K=\frac{h}{6}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
4 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

This simple codes implements the idea, but my numerical solution is scaled by a factor of $(2h)$: if you set `u/(2*h)` instead of `u`, you'll get the right solution exact at grid points).

**I think the source of error should be in how I define the step $h$, because those midpoints are confusing me a bit, but I can't figure out how to fix this**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate


a = 0.0
b = 1.0
N = 8
h = (b-a)/(N)

nodes = [0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1.0]
elements = [[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8]]


def assembly_stiff_quadratic():
    A = np.array([[7,-8,1],[-8,16,-8],[1,-8,7]])
    return (A)/(3.0*(h))
    
    
def assembly_load_quadratic():
    return ((h)/6.0)*np.array([1,4,1])



numK = len(elements)
numV = len(nodes)
A = np.zeros([numV,numV])
f = np.zeros(numV)


for K in range (0,numK):
    loc2glb = elements[K]
    AK = assembly_stiff_quadratic()
    print(K,loc2glb)
    bK = assembly_load_quadratic()
    A[np.ix_(loc2glb,loc2glb)] += AK
    f[np.ix_(loc2glb)]+=bK



f = f[1:-1]
A = A[1:-1,1:-1]
u = np.linalg.solve(A,f)


def sol(x):
    return -(0.5)*x*(x-1)

x = np.linspace(0,1,N+1)
plt.plot(x[1:-1],u,'o')
plt.plot(x[1:-1],sol(x[1:-1]),'r')
```

My question is not about debugging the code, rather about how to do the assembly in this case. I posted the code because I think it is straightforward to read and easy to test.

**EDIT:**

After the comments, I wrote the following snippet which produces the following order of convergence plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate



a = 0.0
b = 1.0
def solvePoisson(N): 
    h = 2*(b-a)/(N)


    elements=[]
    for i in range(0,int(N-1)):

        if i%2==0: elements.append([j for j in range(i,i+3)])
    nodes= np.linspace(a,b,N+1)

    def phi0(x):
        return (1-x)*(1-2*x)

    def phi1(x):
        return 4*x*(1-x)

    def phi2(x):
        return x*(2*x-1)
    
    def rhs(x):
        return np.sin(x)    


    def assembly_stiff_quadratic():
        A = np.array([[7,-8,1],[-8,16,-8],[1,-8,7]])
        return (A)/(3.0*(h))

    numK = len(elements)
    numV = len(nodes)
    A = np.zeros([numV,numV])
    f = np.zeros(numV)



    for K in range (0,numK):
        loc2glb = elements[K]
        AA = nodes[loc2glb[0]]
#        BB = nodes[loc2glb[2]]
        AK = assembly_stiff_quadratic()
        bK = h*np.array([integrate.quadrature(lambda x: rhs(AA+h*x)*phi0(x),0,1)[0],integrate.quadrature(lambda x: rhs(AA+h*x)*phi1(x),0,1)[0],integrate.quadrature(lambda x: rhs(AA+h*x)*phi2(x),0,1)[0]])

        A[np.ix_(loc2glb,loc2glb)] += AK
        f[np.ix_(loc2glb)]+=bK



    f = f[1:-1]
    A = A[1:-1,1:-1]
    u = np.linalg.solve(A,f)
    return u

def sol(x):
    return np.sin(x) - x *np.sin(1)


N = 8
x = np.linspace(0,1,N+1) 
plt.plot(x[1:-1],solvePoisson(N),'o')
plt.plot(x[1:-1],sol(x[1:-1]),'r')
```

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure: you asked a very similar question and Dr. Bangerth answered it. Why aren't you following his advice?

Comment: Actually I think I was following his advice: in each element I have three numbers. Also, my assignment sheet explicitly tells me to use those two arrays `nodes` and `elements` @AbdullahAliSivas

Comment: What he is suggesting is to have some sort of abstraction layer separating the vertices of the mesh from the nodes of an element. In your case, vertices would be 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1.0 and you would be integrating over [0,0.25], [0.25,05] and so on. The nodes would determine the polynomials you use and they would be sampled more frequently. If you want to keep your code the same, h should be twice the value it is now.

Comment: That's the point I'm missing: why should h be doubled? @AbdullahAliSivas Thanks for your time

Comment: Think of the mesh as a tessellation of the domain, i.e., $T=\{K\}$. Then on each mesh element $K$, you define a finite element (particularly, Cea's definition, but the modern interpretation is slightly different to allow some exotic elements): the nodes, corresponding polynomials, etc. In your case, 1D, the mesh is [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0], then on each $K$ you have a finite element with the nodes $[k_0, (k_0+k_1)/2, k_1]$ and the corresponding polynomials $\phi_0,\phi_1,\phi_2$. So the matrix entries you compute are $A^K_{i,j} = \int_K \phi_i\phi_j$ which introduces $h=|K|$.

Comment: If you say that $h$ must be doubled, it's like if you are saying that there are $4$ intervals, rather than $8$. I think that now I'm starting to have a clearer picture: for instance, since $[0,0.25] $ is an element, then it must be $h=0.25$. In my codes, it's like if I'm considering that each node is a vertex (which is true only for 1d linear elements actually) @AbdullahAliSivas Is that correct?

Comment: I've just seen your last comment. I got the difference now: every vertex is a node, but in general it's not true that every node is a vertex

Comment: Your last assertion is not true either. Vertices are nodes, for example, if you are using Lagrange polynomials. But if you were to use Legendre polynomials then the nodes and the vertices would be two completely different sets.

Comment: Ups, I said that because I've only seen Lagrange polynomials. One last point: in case I have a non-constant r.h.s, let's say $f(x)=sin(x)$, and I want to loop over the elements, I have to compute for each element the vector of $3$ integrals $$\int_0^1 f(x) \hat{\phi}_idx$$ and put this into position `loc2glb`of the load vector $f$, where $\hat{\phi}_i$ are the basis function in the reference element $[0,1]$. By doing so but my numerical solution is again a bit shifted w.r.t the true one, and the source of the error must be in the integration of the load vector @AbdullahAliSivas

Comment: Actually, I just realised that I should change also $f(x)$ if I want to integrate over the reference element. The canonical map in 1D is $\phi(\xi)=x_i + \xi h$. So I changed $f(x)$ in the scipy integration routine with $f(x_i + \xi h)$ where $\xi$ is the integration variable. All in all, the resulting integral is $$\int_0^1 f(x_K +\xi h) \hat{\phi_i}(\xi) h d \xi$$ where $x_K$ is the vertex of the K-th element I'm integrating, and $I=1,2,3$ refers to the bubble functions on the reference element $[0,1]$.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas I tested the order of convergence for the case where $f=\sin(x)$, and I obtain the plot in the edit, which shows third order convergence. I think this confirms my implementation because for the $L2$ norm we have $$||u - u_h|| \leq C h^{s+1}|u|_{H^{s+1}}$$ where $s= \min\{2,p \}$ and $p$ such that $u \in C^0 \cap H^{p+1}$. Here $u$ is actually $C^{\infty}$ so $s=2$ and hence the $L2$ bound should confirm 3rd order of convergence. Is this correct? If this is correct I have no more questions :-)

Comment: It looks fine to me :)